# How to get the perfect WordPress, WooCommerce, Custom Post Type pretty permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like some clarification on how to achieve the following structure:

---

**Posts & Categories**
domain.com/blog/ - Blog index
domain.com/blog/%category%/ - Blog category archive
domain.com/blog/%category%/%sub-category%/%post-name%/ Single Post

**Pages & Child Pages**
domain.com/%page%/ - Single Page
domain.com/%page%/%child-page%/ - Single Child page

**WooCommerce Products & Categories**
domain.com/shop/ - Shop index
domain.com/shop/%category%/ - "Product Category" taxonomy archive
domain.com/shop/%category%/%sub-category%/%product-name%/ Single product

---

I would really love to get a definitive answer as this seems to be a constant problem for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

But if you have a lot of pages and posts and a top ranked website, I suggest using the following structure which is fully optimized and server friendly:

```
/%post_id%/%postname%/
```